# Sets: True or False

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is to determine whether the following statement is True or False:

**If x belongs to A and A is not a subset of B, then x belongs to B.**

The answer given in book is **False** but according to me it can be true also.
Suppose $x = 1$, $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $B = \{4, 5, 1\}$. Here, $A$ is not a subset of $B$, but $x$ belongs to both $A$ and $B$.

So I'm basically confused what is the right answer TRUE or FALSE. Experts please tell me what is the right answer.

Comment: The question implicitly asks if this is true whatever $x\in A$ you chose. And in your example, it is not true for $x=2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net u mean that since it is not true in every situation that's y it is FALSE.

Comment: Okay @JoséCarlosSantos I will check that

Comment: Personally I would go for the terminology NOT TRUE IN GENERAL instead of FALSE.

Comment: Since no further context is given, we can safely assume that $x$ , $A$ and $B$ are arbitary , and then it is easy to construct a counterexample which is enough to refute the statement. Even if it would be true in all cases except one , it would still be false.

Answer (score 2):

As a statement, it is clearly not true. As a general advice, whenever you have **if...then** like statement in math, consider it as implication. Namely, "If A then B" can be written as **$A \implies B$**, and in your case that is not true, as this in mathematical terms asks if $$((x \in A) \land (A\not \subset B))\implies(x \in B)$$
So if you can find at least one counterexample where the left hand side of implication holds and right doesn't, then it is considered to be False